# Saving binary file content in string to be able to md5 it and compare to other files later on

Tags: c++

I would like to save a md5 of a image file in a database so when a user sends another image I would like to be able to compare if the image already exists in the database, I have to know if theres already one of those in the database, I thought the easiest way would be to md5 the content of a file and then compare with the md5 output to see if they are equal or not.

how could I do that? if you think this is not very good to do, you could suggest something else to compare images without having the original file present at the moment, that's why I'm saving the md5 in the database.

I have the md5 function but I don't know what to md5, my md5 function accept a std::string parameter and return the result as a std::string.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think MD5 is the way to go. Any image processing operation to compare images will probably take longer than the MD5 calculation.

Now, you need to **break this operation into smaller steps**:

**1 -** Read a file in binary mode into a `std::string`:

```
string data;
string filename("file.bin");
ifstream input_file( filename.c_str(), ios::binary | ios::in );
if( !input_file)
{
    cout << "!!! Failed to open file";
    // exit/return
}

std::ostringstream ss;
ss << input_file.rdbuf();
data = ss.str();

input_file .close();
```

**2 -** Retrieve the MD5 of the file:

```
std::string md5_hash = compute_md5(data);
```

Comment: That's what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you need the database to be persistant just use a database API like sqlite, and save the images (as a blob) in the database with the hash has it's primary key. If it does not, then just store the hash in a `std::map` or a `std::unordered_map`, this way you can index an image with a hash.

```
 std::string image=load_image("my_image.jpg");
 std::string db=make_hash(image);
 std::map<std::string, std::string> db;
 db[hash]=image;
```

Or something like that, I personally wouldn't store an image as a `std::string` it would depend on the image types you are working with. But that is another question i think.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map

http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html

Comment: I would like to avoid that, I would like to avoid using Blob because my database would be gigantic, I just want to make the processing as the program is going to store a small amount in the database, just an md5 to compare, that's all. do you know how to do this ?

Comment: @Grego Instead of using a blob put the file path or unique identifier that you have to retrieve the image, what you are after is an associative container like a map or a database.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering but using md5 is the best answer, it makes a simple 32 bit solution as in the answer of @karlphillip

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to do if you can/want to use Qt/C++. You can even design a simple UI to

- Open a file dialog to select an image file - See [QFileDialog](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html)
- Display image - See [QLabel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlabel.html), [QPixmap](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html)
- Calculate SHA1 hash - See [QCryptographicHash](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QCryptographicHash.html)

  ```
  QString sha1Hash = QCryptographicHash::hash(bytes, QCryptographicHash::Sha1).toHex();
  ```
- Query database *does this hash already exists?* - See: [Qt SQL module](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtsql.html)

  ```
  bool isRegistered(const QString hash){

     QSqlQuery query(QSqlDatabase::database("default"));

     query.prepare("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM pixmap WHERE hash=?");
     query.bindValue(0, sha1Hash);
     query.exec();

     if(query.first()){
         return query.value(0).toInt() > 0;
     }

     return false; // It isn't
  }
  ```

(I haven't tried this code, it's just a raw sketch)

- If the image is not there, register current timestamp(?), hash, path and filename in database and then copy image to a preset directory.